# Make an infinite supply of snowballs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How could I use a command to give a player an infinite supply of snowballs that do 5 hearts of damage? There was a bug where you could summon infinite items in snapshot 13w36a, which right here:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:<id>,count:128}}
```

The item count is set to 128, which is what I believe causes this glitch, Unfortunately after reading around a bit, I was led to believe that this bug was patched, due to being prevelant in a development snapshot. So, how could I summon an infinite supply of snowballs that do 5 hearts of damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The infinite supply bug (Which I think they actually added on purpose) still works fine. Your problem there is rather simple, you just forgot to capitalise the "C" in "count". This should work properly:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:snowball,Count:128}}
```

The wiki has some nice pages on NBT data which I use to get the format and names right:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_Format
(Players and items)
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format
(Everything else)

Doing 5 hearts of damage is not something that NBT data can do to a snowball; I don't even think any data is carried over from the snowball item to the thrown snowball entity. The best you could do is perhaps have a fast clock with this on it:

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /effect @p[r=2] 7 10 1
```

Which would make a thrown snowball constantly give players within 2 blocks (changeable) instant damage II for 10 ticks. The thrower would also likely take damage though, and it would be subject to lag.

Answer (score -2):

2014 says it is true, but now its not. The only way to spawn INF# snowballs or any object is to glitch it.

There isn't a command except the blockdata one.