# Can you make snowballs deal damage using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if it was possible to make snowballs deal damage to players and mobs, using command blocks?

I'm playing Minecraft 1.7.10

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much damage will my Snowball do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178721/how-much-damage-will-my-snowball-do)

Comment: That question ask how much do they do to blaze. Snowballs only damgae mobs so i want to make them damage playera

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an infinite supply of snowballs](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169052/make-an-infinite-supply-of-snowballs)

Comment: This question is either asking for a mod recommendation or asking how do develop a mod. Neither of these would be on-topic.

Comment: Using command blocks...

Comment: @kingbluesapphire - I've added the Command Blocks requirement to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /effect @e[r=3] 7 1 1
```

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted one, I'd much rather have the 2nd answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think not, but in 1.8 you can beacause of replace. Detect if a player is in 0.1 block range of the player, then replace the snowball with an arrow or other things. You can do cool things like detect if a snowball is in range of a gold block, put a diamond on the gold block, or you could do this but with an egg that has an 0% chance of hatching a chicken.

Anyway, you can do some similar but cooler things using bukkit.
either update to 1.8(out now) or use bukkit. I recommend using bukkit.